# Acceder atributos de un objeto dentro de un array en JS

Tags: javascript

Creo un objeto con 3 parámetros, y lo inserto en un array. Ahora, cuando recorro el array, siempre me sale `undefined`, y he probado varias cosas, pero nada.

Éste es mi código:

```js
//***************************  Arrays ***************************
//El que va a contener todos los votos, el que recorro que dentro tiene los objetos.
var contenedor = [];
var colegiosPrueba = ["Virgen Pilar"];
var partidos = ["PP", "PSOE", "Podemos", "Ciudadanos", "IU"];

//Por cada colegio, coge un voto de cada partido
function aVotar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < colegiosPrueba.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < partidos.length; j++) {
      var aux = prompt(colegiosPrueba[i] + "--" + partidos[j]);
      voto(colegiosPrueba[i], partidos[j], aux);
      contenedor.push(voto);
    }
  }
}

//Ver array
function verArray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < contenedor.length; i++) {
    var auxi = parseInt((contenedor[i].getColegio));

  }
}

function voto(colegio, partido, numeroVotos) {
  this.colegio = colegio;
  this.partido = partido;
  this.numeroVotos = numeroVotos;

  this.getColegio = function(colegio) {
    return this.votos[colegio];
  }
  this.getPartido = function(partido) {
    return this.votos[partido];
  }
  this.getNumeroVotos = function(numeroVotos) {
    return this.votos[numeroVotos];
  }
}

aVotar();
console.log(contenedor);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en estas líneas de código:

```
        voto(colegiosPrueba[i], partidos[j], aux);
        contenedor.push(voto);
```

`voto` es una función que se usa para simular una clase en JavaScript, lo estás llamando pero no estás guardando el resultado en ningún sitio. Luego, haces un `push` de `voto`, que sigue siendo la función... o mejor dicho, el resultado de una función que no devuelve nada. Es por eso que vas a tener `undefined`.

Llama la función usando `new` (como si se tratara del constructor de una clase) y guarda el resultado en una variable. Luego haz `push` de esa variable en el array contenedor para guardar el valor. Algo como esto:

```
            var votoValor = new voto(colegiosPrueba[i], partidos[j], aux);
            contenedor.push(votoValor);
```

De ese modo ya se guardará lo que quieres en lugar de `undefined` como se puede ver en este ejemplo:

> **Nota: esta solución solo se centra en solucionar la parte de recibir `undefined`, el código presenta otros errores que no he solucionado**, porque faltaría información para saber qué o cómo deberían resolverse. Por ejemplo: la función `verArray` está incompleta y llama de manera incorrecta a un método del objeto (`auxi` será siempre NaN porque se está haciendo `parseInt` de una función y no del resultado que devuelve dicha función porque le faltan los paréntesis, pero incluso con paréntesis, la función tiene problemas: ¿qué es `this.votos`? ¿qué parámetro estás pasando?)

```js
//***************************  Arrays ***************************
//El que va a contener todos los votos, el que recorro que dentro tiene los objetos.
var contenedor = [];
var colegiosPrueba = ["Virgen Pilar"];
var partidos = ["PP", "PSOE", "Podemos", "Ciudadanos", "IU"];

//Por cada colegio, coge un voto de cada partido
function aVotar() {
    for (var i = 0; i < colegiosPrueba.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < partidos.length; j++) {
            var aux = prompt(colegiosPrueba[i] + "--" + partidos[j]);
            const votoValor = new voto(colegiosPrueba[i], partidos[j], aux);
            contenedor.push(votoValor);
        }
    }
}

//Ver array
function verArray() {
    for( var i = 0; i<contenedor.length;i++){
        var auxi = parseInt((contenedor[i].getColegio));

    }
}

function voto(colegio, partido, numeroVotos) {
    this.colegio = colegio;
    this.partido = partido;
    this.numeroVotos = numeroVotos;

    this.getColegio = function (colegio) {
        return this.votos[colegio];
    }
    this.getPartido = function (partido) {
        return this.votos[partido];
    }
    this.getNumeroVotos = function (numeroVotos) {
        return this.votos[numeroVotos];
    }
}

aVotar();
console.log(contenedor);
verArray();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.